# Auto-complete method does not get called

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm not sure what is wrong, this is my first time spinning this up. Looking at the ajax examples, all should be working.. but my method does not get called.

I am not making use of a webservice, and want to return my suggestions from a page method.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" CssClass="searchTextBox"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="searchBox_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
  DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServiceMethod="_get_Suggestions"
  TargetControlID="searchBox">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**Page Method:**

```
Private Function _get_Suggestions(prefixText As String, count As Int16) As String()
    Dim array() As String = {"doggy", "catty", "fishy"}
    Return array
End Function
```

Also tried:

```
<WebMethod()> <Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> Public Shared Function _get_Suggestions(prefixText As String, count As Int16) As String()
```

Answer (score 0):

My Extender AND method, was on my masterpage. After some hints on similar issues, it seems I cant have my page method on the masterpage code behind.

I have to put the page method, in my content page, while the extender itself, can be in my masterpage.

Why? No clue... Maybe someone can elaborate to improve this answer.